# Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

Here is the problem : I wanted to make a function that gets a parameter and returns the same type.

I made the simpliest example possible :

```js
type Test = <T>(arg: T) => T;
const test: Test = (arg: string) => arg;
```

This simple implementation of the function of type Test throws the error "Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'"

Can someone explain me why this error occures event when not using props from the templated argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30496 actually has the answer to this: `Test` is a generic type. Your definition does not conform to the generic type because `T` cannot be assigned to `string`. You should be able to use `test<number>(num)` and have it work as well, but that would be incompatible if `arg` were a string.

You can make the type generic, though. This would allow you to narrow the type when you declare the function type.

```
type Test<T> = (arg: T) => T;
const test<string> = arg => arg; //arg is a string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer Explosion Pills. 
The problem was that i have to let the template resolve by itself so i just made the function without specifying type and it works well too.

```js
type Test = <T>(arg: T) => T;
const test: Test = (arg) => arg;
```

And here with the original function i was working on :

```js
type VariableReducer = <T>(
  array: { label: string; value: T }[],
  variable: Readonly<IVariableDescriptor> | undefined,
  key: string,
) => { label: string; value: T }[];

const defaultVariableReducer: VariableReducer = (a, v) =>
  (v !== undefined && v.name !== undefined
    ? [...a, { label: editorLabel(v), value: v.name }]
    : a) as typeof a;
```