# Generics - 'Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T', even with typeof check

Tags: typescript

Studying generics and I've reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270520/type-t-is-not-assignable-to-type-string) but don't understand why my hypothetical example throws a type error even with a `typeof` check.

My understanding is that this function would only return a string if a string is provided to it, so shouldn't that be type-safe?

```js
function foo<T>(value: T):T {
    if(typeof value === 'string'){
        return value.toUpperCase() // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    }
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not type-safe.

Consider the following example:

```
const result = foo("a")
//    ^? const result: "a"

console.log(result) // [LOG]: "A"
```

The return type of the function is `"a"`, but it actually returns `"A"`. We have created a mismatch between type and actual value. When dealing with primitives, you always have to consider that generic types may also be literal types.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgG4CGANiAKYBciGAlORogN4BQiriMwOUAngA6lxgiQiVKIAvJMQByAM5QATjDABzadWZstiBaSggFSEWQB0UOAFVe-BQGECs0jmqIA9K6p8xcxcrXtZRDA4KEQHWRgVMAIAIyIxc0QefhkMaRMWNgBfTNZdfUNhYjImHKZyiAR5HVJZECJQ8WRUHAAiAlbqJnctAD0AfkRKsGrdOobKdtaKqrh4kyI4FRwx+qgXHoBtABkAeQBxAF1JgEFWxCA)

Comment: Thanks, hovering over 'foo' in my IDE I can now see `function foo<"a">(value: "a"): "a"` so I understand what you mean. I guess a follow-up question is why is this literal instead of `string`?

Comment: The details about inferring literal types can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676